# Core Data sharing with CloudKit: Unable to Accept Share

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I had my app working with Core Data, then CloudKit to sync between devices and now I'd like to share data between users. I watched both [Build apps that share data through CloudKit and Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10015/) and [What's new in CloudKit WWDC21](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10086/) and thought that I got the concepts down. CloudKit uses zone sharing and CKShares to handle sharing and Core Data attaches to this implementation natively in iOS15.

I setup my Core Data stack as such:

```
/// Configure private store
guard let privateStoreDescription: NSPersistentStoreDescription = persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
    Logger.model.error("Unable to get private Core Data persistent store description")
    return
}
privateStoreDescription.url = inMemory ? URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null") : privateStoreDescription.url?.appendingPathComponent("\(containerIdentifier).private.sqlite")
privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
privateStoreDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(privateStoreDescription)

/// Create shared store
let sharedStoreDescription: NSPersistentStoreDescription = privateStoreDescription.copy() as! NSPersistentStoreDescription
sharedStoreDescription.url = sharedStoreDescription.url?.appendingPathComponent("\(containerIdentifier).shared.sqlite")
let sharedStoreOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: containerIdentifier)
sharedStoreOptions.databaseScope = .shared
sharedStoreDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = sharedStoreOptions
persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(sharedStoreDescription)
persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores(...)
```

Implemented the SceneDelegate user acceptance:

```
func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, userDidAcceptCloudKitShareWith cloudKitShareMetadata: CKShare.Metadata) {
    let container = PersistenceController.shared.persistentContainer
    let sharedStore = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first!
    container.acceptShareInvitations(from: [cloudKitShareMetadata], into: sharedStore, completion: nil) //TODO: Log completion
}
```

However after sharing the NSObject as such in my UI using `UICloudSharingController` as seen below:

```
let object: NSObject = // Get Object from view context
let container = PersistenceController.shared.persistentContainer
let cloudSharingController = UICloudSharingController { (controller, completion: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) in
    container.share([object], to: nil) { objectIDs, share, container, error in
        completion(share, container, error)
        Logger.viewModel.debug("Shared \(household.getName())")
    }
}
cloudSharingController.delegate = self
self.present(cloudSharingController, animated: true) {}
```

My SceneDelegate method is never called and I get the following alert when I press the invite from the messages app. I'm not quite sure what is wrong in this case as on the CloudKit developer console I see the object in a private database with the zone of com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.share.[UUID]. I have not released the app yet so I'm not sure where it is getting version information from as both apps were launched from the Xcode debugger(same version & build). Additionally I was unable to find reference this alert on other questions so any advice, suggestions, or help is welcome as I have been stuck on this for a few evenings. Please let me know if there is more information that could shine light on this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was solved when I added the CKSharingSupported key with a Bool value of true in the Info.plist

After that I was able to share with no problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the help! Searching for that plist key showed a small handful of mentions. Looks like I overlooked it as it was not mentioned in the latest video. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cksharingsupported)

Comment: FYI. I had this issue as well but I already had CKSharingSupported = 1 in both Info.plist and the Info tab. I had to delete it and re-add it to the Info.plist before things started working.